# Working on a C# hangman game, cant figure out how to detect multiple letters

Tags: c#, regex

Im a newbie, so I decided to make a hangman game, but I've arrived at a problem. The game works perfectly for words that don't have duplicate letters (juice, chair, fun). I have the word be chosen at random from a list of all words from the English dictionary, and whenever I get a word with multiple letters (apple, cookie, balloon) it only uncovers the first occurrence of that letter.

The code is about 100 lines, so I put it on pastebin for convenience: http://pastebin.com/tWRqweQg

I've tried a few ways of doing it, but none of the ideas I've had have come to fruition. Some of my ideas as follows:

> - Use a for loop to add each word to a list. If the next character iteration is in that list... (lost here)
> - Make a method return true or false depending on if the guessed character is found more than once in the word (Then what?)
> - A few other incomplete ideas

There's gotta be a way to do it. If you want an idea of what im talking about, just set the word  variable in my code to a string with multiple letters. Any help would be much appreciated!

PS: I dont understand the lines of code that are go along the lines of:
if (a = x for i in q[1].append) [terrible example] or otherwise complicated code. If the code needs to be long and inefficient, thats fine! Ill learn efficiency later!

Comment: Please post the relevant code that deals with the exact thing you're having trouble with... which is, what exactly? You're having trouble detecting words with duplicate letters, or uncovering the duplicates when the letter is guessed, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a simple fix here is the code

```
if (j.Equals(leguess))// If the character = the letter guess
{
    int index = word.IndexOf(j);// Get the index of j
    while (index > -1)
    {
        guess = guess.Remove(index, 1).Insert(index, j.ToString());
        index = word.IndexOf(j, index + 1);
    }
}
```

I have inserted a while loop to replace all the occurrence in the guessed word

Comment: Oh i see, and i think i've got the logic down too. if the string hasn't been searched completely (while index > -1), set "index" to the index of the searched character, but add 1 because counting doesn't start at 0 (only indexing does). For some reason i thought to use a for loop to iterate through this (Which i probably could). This helped me alot, thanks a thousand!

Comment: That's great! btw I like the simplicity of the game. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your foreach

```
foreach (char j in wordchar)// Iterate through every character
{

    if (j.Equals(leguess))// If the character = the letter guess
    {
        int index = word.IndexOf(j);// Get the index of j
        guess = guess.Remove(index, 1).Insert(index, j.ToString());
    }

}
```

With this code

```
int index = -1;
while ((index = word.IndexOf(leguess, index+1)) != -1)
    guess = guess.Remove(index, 1).Insert(index, leguess);
```